# Why the restrictions on C standard I/O streams that interact with sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, io, c-standard-library

In book CSAPP section 10.9, it says that there are two restrictions on standard I/O streams that interact badly with restrictions on sockets.

> Restriction 1: Input functions following output functions. An input function cannot follow an output function without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos, or rewind. The fflush function empties the buffer associated with a stream. The latter three functions use the Unix I/O lseek function to reset the current ﬁle position.
>
> Restriction 2: Output functions following input functions. An output function cannot follow an input function without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos, or rewind, unless the input function encounters an end-of-ﬁle.

But I cannot figure out why the restrictions imposed. So, my question is: what factors result to the two restrictions?

It also says that "It is illegal to use the lseek function on a socket.", but how is it possible `fseek`, `fsetpos` and `rewind` use `lseek` to reset the current file position if it is true?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605967/restriction-of-c-standard-i-o-and-why-we-cant-use-c-standard-i-o-with-sockets), but my question different from this one.

Comment: Note that these restrictions are only if you open the stream in *update mode* (using `'+'` in the call to [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) or [`fdopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html)). If you open the stream in read-only or write-only modes, those restrictions doesn't apply.

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14354269/5335565; due to the buffer implementation of the stdio, the stdio file position may differ from the OS file position.  when you read 1 bytes, stdio mark the file position to 1. Due to the buffering, stdio may read 1024 bytes from the underlying file, where OS would record its file position at 1024. When you switch to output, you really need to choose which position you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdio` functions are for *buffered file input and output*. A socket is not a file, but a socket. It doesn't even have a file position, and the buffer requirements are quite distinct from ordinary files - sockets can have independent input and output buffers, stdio file I/O cannot!

The problem is that the *file input* and *file output* share the *same* file position, and the operating system might have (and indeed will have on Unix) a distinct file position from what the file position due to the buffering in C would be.

Hence, from C99 rationale

> A change of input/output direction on an update file is only allowed following a successful
> `fsetpos`, `fseek`, `rewind`, or `fflush` operation, since these are precisely the functions
> which assure that the I/O buffer has been flushed.

Note that all this applies to only files opened with `+` - with files opened in any other standard modes, it is not possible to mix input and output.

Since it is required by the C standard that when switching from *input* to *output* on `FILE *` one of the functions `fsetpos`, `rewind` or `fseek`, which essentially invoke `lseek` must be successful (mind you, calling `fflush` causes the buffered output to be written, and certainly not discarding the buffered input) before an output function is attempted... yet a socket is not seekable and `lseek` would therefore always *fail* - it means that you cannot use a `FILE *` that has been opened for both reading and writing wrapping the socket for actually both *reading from* and *writing to* the socket.

---

It is possible to use `fdopen` to open a `FILE *` with stream sockets if you really need to: just open **two** files - one `"rb"` for input and *another* with `"wb"` for output.

Comment: So, not only socket streams have these two restrictions but also normal disk file streams?

Comment: @Alaneuler  emphatically **no**, you're completely misunderstanding what the quote means. I don't have the book but I am pretty sure it means "these restrictions are the reason why sockets are not ordinarily wrapped into a `FILE *`.

Comment: OK... from what I know, `FILE *` stream share the same file descriptor, so they share the same file position, do you mean input and output have distinct file position due to buffering (e.g., from very beginning, input and output both have file position 0, one reading of a `char` causes input position to 1 while output is still 0; then a writing of 10 `char` causes output position to 10 while input position is still 1)? What about the file position in file table?

Comment: @Alaneuler A `FILE *` has its *own* file position that is distinct from the position of the file description.

Comment: There are no *input and output* positions. If you read 1 character with stdio, the file description can be advanced 2048 characters. `ftell` will tell 1. The output position for file description is 2048. There is no output position for stdio... if you write without seek, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the explanations, now I understand the reason for the two restrictions. But I have one final question: you've said that socket is not seekable, but the excerpt says that "The latter three functions (which are `fsetpos`, `rewind` and `fseek`) use the Unix I/O `lseek` function to reset the current ﬁle position", is this wrong in the CSAPP book?

Comment: The book is right. But `lseek` will *fail* on sockets, hence the former three will fail as well.

Comment: "mind you, calling fflush flushes the output, not input buffer!". do you imply the stdio has different buffer for input and output? it contradicts to what you said:
"sockets can have independent input and output buffers, stdio file I/O cannot!"

Comment: @Izana fixed. I am not purposely implying anything - it is not even specified by the standard if there are separate input and output buffers or not.

Answer (score 0):

When it says "An input function cannot follow an output function without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos, or rewind", what it means is that if you don't, it might not work as you expect.  But they're mostly talking about i/o to/from ordinary files.

If you have a `FILE *` stream connected to a socket, and you want to switch back and forth between writing and reading, I would expect it to work just fine if you called `fflush` when switching from writing to reading.  I would not expect it to be necessary to call anything when switching from reading to writing.

(When working with files, the call to `fseek` or one of its relatives is necessary in order to update the file position properly, but streams don't have a file position to update.)

Comment: That's incorrect actually. There is no function you can call after input to switch to output. (Except in POSIX.1-2008)

Comment: @Steve Summit just cannot grab what you want to point, can you elaborate?

Comment: From what I understand currently, if you are working with normal disk file `FILE *` stream, there is no such restriction, you can freely switch back and forth between writing and reading. But with `FILE *` stream on socket, you have to do the extra work between switching. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alaneuler That doesn't match my understanding -- I stand by my answer.  But Antti Haapala seems to be disagreeing with my answer, so I can't be perfectly sure.  (And I haven't had time to test anything.)

Comment: While you can use fflush to switch from writing to reading on a FILE connected to a (SOCK_STREAM) socket, that does not work the other way.  In fact there IS NO SAFE WAY to switch from reading to writing on a FILE connected to a socket -- data may be lost.  There are also problems using FILE with non-STREAM sockets, as there is no way to manage the message boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that, in the early days, the buffer is shared for read and write for most implementations.

The rationale is simple, most cases are uni-direction. And maintain 2 buffers for read and write respectively wastes space.

If you have only one buffer, when you change the IO direction, you need to deal with the buffer. That's why you need `fflush, fseek, fsetpos, or rewind` to either write the buffer to disk or empty the buffer in preparation for the next IO operation.

I checked one glibc implementation, which only uses one single buffer for read and write.

```c
static void init_stream (register FILE *fp) {
    ...
    fp->__buffer = (char *) malloc (fp->__bufsize);

   if (fp->__bufp == NULL)
    {
      /* Set the buffer pointer to the beginning of the buffer.  */
      fp->__bufp = fp->__buffer;
      fp->__put_limit = fp->__get_limit = fp->__buffer;
    }
}
```

take [fseek](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/libc-970720/stdio/fseek.c#42) for example

```
/* Move the file position of STREAM to OFFSET
   bytes from the beginning of the file if WHENCE
   is SEEK_SET, the end of the file is it is SEEK_END,
   or the current position if it is SEEK_CUR.  */
int
fseek (stream, offset, whence)
     register FILE *stream;
     long int offset;
     int whence;
{
  ...
  if (stream->__mode.__write && __flshfp (stream, EOF) == EOF)
    return EOF;
  ...
  /* O is now an absolute position, the new target.  */
  stream->__target = o;
  /* Set bufp and both end pointers to the beginning of the buffer.
     The next i/o will force a call to the input/output room function.  */
  stream->__bufp
    = stream->__get_limit = stream->__put_limit = stream->__buffer;
  ...
}
```

this implementation would **flush** the buffer to disk file if it's write mode.

And it will reset the pointer for both read and write. It's equivalent to reset or flush the buffer for read.

It matches the C99 (credit to the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52850409/5335565))

> A change of input/output direction on an update file is only allowed following a successful fsetpos, fseek, rewind, or fflush operation, since these are precisely the functions which assure that the I/O buffer has been flushed.

For more details, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71390193/5335565).